# Why does dockerised SSH service not start since it can not load host-keys?

Tags: docker, ssh

I am trying to dockerize an SSH service/daemon not unlikely as described here: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/#build-an-eg_sshd-image

In the container, when I try to `/usr/sbin/sshd` I get

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

I tried to `ssh-keygen -A` and manually:

```
user@3df98eeeb0d7:/home/dev/$ sudo ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N ''
```

But, after failing to load host keys again after `/usr/sbin/sshd`, I am still  not successful:

```
user@3df98eeeb0d7:/home/dev/$ /etc/init.d/ssh status
 * sshd is not running
```

Since the creation of new keys is not working, I do not have a clue how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need super user rights

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Solves your problem. Although on most containers your user runs all commands in root context.